# Altair yaxis limits free

Tags: python, altair

I am trying to play with altair python visualization library and got the facet function working. However, in the plot all the facets have same y-lim. I want to know if it is possible to implement similar to ggplot2 facet(~column, scales = "free"). Is there a way to implement scales == "free" in altair ? I looked at the documentation and I saw that there aren't other variables that I can adjust.

The code that I am using is as follows:

```
alt.Chart(sum_tf).mark_line().encode(
    x='month:Q',
    y='value:Q',
).properties(
    width=600,
    height=100
).facet(
    facet='variable:O',
    columns=1
)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `resolve_scale` setting to control whether scales within compound charts are shared or independent. By default, scales are shared:

```
alt.Chart(sum_tf).mark_line().encode(
    x='month:Q',
    y='value:Q',
).properties(
    width=600,
    height=100
).facet(
    facet='variable:O',
    columns=1
).resolve_scale(
    y='independent'
)
```

More information and examples in the docs here: https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/scale_resolve.html

Comment: +1 Awesome thank you so much. I was not aware of this option. I am learning altair is the most intuitive visualization library in python. Especially after coming from R world altair has been life saver. Also is there a way to visualize altair in pycharm / spyder ?

Comment: https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/faq.html#does-altair-work-with-ipython-terminal-pycharm-spyder-my-favorite-ide